# How To Add Resources Without Compatibility Error?

Tags: c#, winapi, resources, compatibility

The code below creates a copy of the application and adds resources to the copy. When you run the copy that has resources in it, **it does it's job** first. But when it exits, it exits with Program Compatibility Assistant error:

[image]
Image is from Google.

```
class Program
{
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern IntPtr BeginUpdateResource([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string filename, bool deleteExistingResources);
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern bool UpdateResource(IntPtr resource, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string type, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string name, ushort language, IntPtr data, uint dataSize);
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern bool EndUpdateResource(IntPtr resource, bool discardChanges);

    private static void modifyResources(string filename)
    {
        IntPtr handle = BeginUpdateResource(filename, true);
        UpdateResource(handle, "10", "1", 0, Marshal.StringToHGlobalAnsi("hello world"), (uint) 11);
        EndUpdateResource(handle, false);
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string exeFilename = Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName;
        string filename = Path.GetFileName(exeFilename);
        string anotherFilename = exeFilename.Replace(filename, "_" + filename);
        File.Copy(exeFilename, anotherFilename, true);
        modifyResources(anotherFilename);
    }
}
```

I don't get it. What mistakes do I make ?

More infos: Win 7 64x, App 86x

---

**Notes** *(some of these **made me think** the error was gone)*:

- maybe cleaning up imported libraries might help
- maybe Assemblyname or namespace
- seems the Compatibility Assistant checks too much and thinks something is wrong when the program does something different than the assistant expects.
- project as single exe, no extra dlls (since extinguishing my extra dll, no error occurred)
- **definitely:** error is not running-code related (empty main method)
- **definitely:** error is filename related

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is the acquisitiveness of people! There are file names that are **unwanted** on Windows. Microsoft seems to prevent people from writing new installers. They spawn *compatibility errors* to prevent certain software from becoming popular and spreading.

**Example:**

If you use Resource Hacker (tested on Win7):

1. Go to the installation directory of Resource Hacker.

   - Run it, close it. No problem,
2. Rename *`ResHacker.exe`* to *`ResH Installer acker.exe`*

   - Run it, close it, see the problem.
3. Rename it to *`ResH 4kj545ui45kj4 acker.exe`*

   - Run it, close it. No problem.
4. Rename it back to *`ResHacker.exe`*

**Punchline:**

```
if (exeFilename.Contains("Installer") && exeFile.isCapableOfResourceManipulation())
    makeProblem();
else
    ignore();
// assembly info is checked too
// confirmed: after removing all unwanted keywords the error stays away
//            even in my old project
```